# How to deal with a large number of external stripe IDs in the domain

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, stripe-payments, domain-driven-design

I want to create a new subscription plan for my customer with stripe. Over a rest request, I get the internal `planId` the customer wants to subscribe to. Now for the stripe api however, I need their `stripePlanId`. Basically, I can get it through a simple lookup of the `pricingPlanRepository`. However, I currently designed my repositories in a way, that they never return the JPA entities, but map to a domain object first, so that my domain is entirely free of any JPA / ORM related logic. That was always fine, so far.

Now however, to create a new subscription in my database, I need to persist a `SubscriptionEntity` - it has a foreign key to a pricing plan - THAT `PricingPlanEntity` I had just retrieved before…

Now I can:

1. break my general architecture design and return the raw entity from the `pricingPlanRepository` and reuse that to create a `SubscriptionEntity`. **Possible, but feels wrong.**
2. Keep my current architecture design and retrieve the `PricingPlanEntity`, then map it to a `PricingPlan` domain object. To avoid retrieving it again, I could do a: `entityManager.getReference(PricingPlanEntity.class, pricingPlanId)`  to retrieve a proxy entity object for the foreign key so I dont have to do the same lookup again. Not sure however 100% what JPA internally does there. MAGIC. **Possible, but feels wrong.**
3. Similar to 2) but instead of retrieving the entire `PricingPlanEntity` I could do a native query to only lookup the `stripePricingPlanId`. That feels more light weight, but a quick google check tells such native queries are actually agains the idea of JPA in the first place and therefore are not recommended. **Possible, but feels wrong.**
4. I could also change my design and directly return the stripe ID to the frontend. But that would make me even more closely bind me to stripe. **Possible, but feels wrong.**
5. Vague brainstorming – maybe a internal / external key lookup table could solve this? I could store the key type, and then with the customer ID I could lookup any kind of stripe ID I would need? No idea if bad or good.

6)???

Sorry, I am lost – what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I think #2 is a sensible approach here. Per the Hibernate docs, unless you access the  proxy object's fields it will not result in an extra query to load the record from the database:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1077

However, I think you're missing another entity type here: you have an opaque reference to a Stripe ID, which is the thing you really need to make the Stripe API call—why not introduce an ExternalReference entity (for example) that maps an internal types + IDs to an external one. A simple table like this would work:

`CREATE TABLE external_references (id PRIMARY KEY, type VARCHAR, external_id VARCHAR)`

Your domain logic can pass around domain objects, and when your code that interfaces with the API needs to find that ID it asks the domain object to look up its external reference ID, or asks the external reference repository to find the reference ID for this domain object.

Comment: for every customer, I have at least 6 external stripe IDs. The internal ID could be the ID of 6 different tables, so there can't be a foreign key relation. Whenever a new stripe ID is received a new entry in this mapping table would have to be created - and whenever any of these ids is removed, a clean up would have to be performed. Not sure if that is really a good solution either.